# How to execute python script in asp.net on load

Tags: javascript, python, asp.net, .net

I have a python code that scrape a webpage for currency convert. i did this one before for my php project and got to reuse it again. but dont know how to do with asp.net.. please help if there is any error on javascript code, or is there another way to execute python .py file from asp.net directly

I did it before by executing python shell using javascript before. and this function was kept on load on html body tag home page. But same code is not working on aspnet. i kept console log on javascript and it was executed. but further tasks was not executed, neither it shows any error on console. please help if there is any error on javascript code, or is there another way to execute python .py file from asp.net directly

this is my rategenerator.py

---

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
calls_df = pd.read_html("https://www.nepalbank.com.np/exchange-rate")
calls_df[0].to_csv('rates.csv', index=False)
```

---

this is my loadFile.js with function loadExternalfile() which in onLoad() on html body tag

---

```
function loadExternalfile() {
    console.log("testing this");
    return
    var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    shell.run("python rategenerator.py");
    return
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'rategenerator.py',
        cache: false,
        async: 'asynchronous',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            console.log("Error: " + error)
        }
    });
    return
    $.ajax({
        url: "../../rategenerator.py",
        context: document.body
    }).done(function () {
        alert('finished python script');;
    });
    return
    var pathToFIle = "../../rategenerator.py"
    var make_shell_ready = escapeShellcmd(pathToFIle);
    return shell_exec(make_shell_ready);
}
```

it was working perfectly in my previous php project. javascript was loaded onload, which executes rategenerator.py, which generates "rates.csv" file. i needed exactly same in this case as well. but in asp, js was loaded and console.log is showing output. but there is no csv file generated. i dont know if python file is executed or not.

Comment: have a look at ironpython

Answer (score 0):

if u have already a python script then you can create a bat file containing
python filepath/filename.py
and then execute it at backend using
Process.Start("path to bat file");